# Google Groups unable to resolve host

Tags: timeout, google-groups

I am not able to get to Google Groups using my desktop, though my smartphone is able to access the site.

```
This webpage is not available.

The webpage at http://groups.google.com/grphp?hl=en might be temporarily down or it may have moved permanently to a new web address.
```

I cannot even ask for help from Google because you are routed to *groups.google.com*! Is there a way to check if my IP was blocked? Or is there another **Help** section where I can contact Google?

Comment: clear your browser cache/use a different browser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using Windows, try refreshing your DNS Cache:

```
ipconfig /flushdns
```